# How does the neofetch ascii logo determine which color to use?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am making custom ascii text-images for a cli app, and was curious how these custom colors are designed.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by designed?

Comment: @jordanm the generation of the ascii art itself. I understand how it's colored for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at neofetch script on it [github page](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch), and search for any distro to see the ascii logo, you will see some codes between some letters, this codes are interpreted by the terminal as a character code indicating "hey start red now..", you can see how it is simple on they wiki page on the colors [section](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Customizing-Info), is pretty like printing colored text code with echo, but they use an "info" method to print and a "color" method to pass the number of the color it want to use. They are both helpers method on the script.